# Is it possible to make the scrollbar absolute positioned only using css like in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a custom scrollbar which looks good on chrome, but my question is it possible to put custom scrollbar absolutely positioned like on mobile device,so that it won't break the menu style 
[image]

This is how it looks when the scrollbar appears, there is a gap between the menu and it looks broken.

[image]

what I want is the menu with `.active` li need to be join with right side border of the `.nav-side-menu` like in image below. The active button need to take full width, there should not be any gap. It need to look like **Image1**

[image]

Is there any way to fix this only using css?

```css
html,
body{margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
/*Scrollbar style*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}

/*Menu Style*/
.nav-side-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #e0e3e4;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
    background-color: #4f5b69;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.nav-side-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.nav-side-menu li a i {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-side-menu li:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 3px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #d3d7d8;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-side-menu li.active {
    box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0 red,inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #f3f6f7;
}


.content-area{
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: #f3f6f7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<div class="nav-side-menu">
  <div class="menu-list">

   <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse">
    <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>

   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="content-area"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making just a small border? That at least eliminates the weird visual effect you’re having.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}


/*Scrollbar style*/

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*Menu Style*/

.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #e0e3e4;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid silver; /* <<<<<<<< Border Here <<<<<<<< */
}

.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #d3d7d8;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-side-menu li.active {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0 red, inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #f3f6f7;
}

.content-area {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: #f3f6f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-side-menu">
  <div class="menu-list">

    <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse">
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="menu_report" href="#">Test</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-area"></div>
```

Also, if that is what you are looking for, you can add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your `.nav-side-menu` to have the space of the scrollbar always present.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not fix my problem. what I want is the menu with `.active` `li`  need to be join with right side border of the `.nav-side-menu`.

Comment: Add that to the main question so others can understand better what you need.

Comment: Try the last part of my answer and see if that helps: “Also, if that is what you are looking for, you can add `overflow-y: scroll`; to your `.nav-side-menu` to have the space of the scrollbar always present.”

Comment: I have updated question, hope everyone can understand it now. Thanks for mentioning this. Also the `overflow-y:scroll` does create gap which I don't want to. What I am looking for is that there should be no space when scrollbar get visible, and scrollbar need to overlap above menu. I hope you get it now

Comment: I think I understand now. I will try later and see.